# Responsive portrait images, Hows & Dont's?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

There's this question bothering me for some time. There are tons tutorials and Q&A's about responsive images, but I haven't found a decent one, that could explain me how to keep the dimensions of a portrait-image not to stretch to the width of the cointainer they are in.

What I have:

I use WordPress, and I remove the width & height of my images with a script:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_thumbnail_dimensions', 10 );

function remove_thumbnail_dimensions( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

And then I add a script, that puts my attachments into a div (just for styling purposes).

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'wrap_my_div', 10, 8);

function wrap_my_div($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){
    return '<div class="post-attachment">'.$html.'</div>';
}
```

and then the CSS:

```
img {
        width: 100%;
}

.post-attachment {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This works really great for landscape images & looks great on mobile. But how to keep images, that are in the portrait dimensions, not to scale to the width of the 100% container? I know, its kind of wierd, if I have declared the width:100% and I don't want some images to be 100% width, but rather 100% height.

[image]

If there isn't a CSS way, then may-be someone can suggest me any jquery plugins (or a WP plugin, though I don't want to use them)? Or some links to dig into?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of width, use max-width:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

That way they will be their original size if they are small, but if they are larger, they will keep within the boundaries of the enclosing parent.

Comment: Well…funny it works in my situation. This seems one of those gotchas, doesn't it?!

Comment: Why was this accepted as the answer? Based on the images you provided you would have to use my solution below in order to restrict the width of portrait image from expanding to the sides of the div. The JSFiddle I provided used max-width: 100%; on the img element, but you'd need to restrict the size of the portrait images in order to achieve what you have in your images above. Maybe I'm missing something...?

Comment: Because he needed fluid images (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/), which will only be re-sized to be contained within their parent, but not enlarged when they are already smaller than their container. Your answer adds markup, and makes them 50%, another fixed size.

Comment: Yes, coopersita is right and appologies for not being 100% precise about what I was after. As I said, your solution isn't wrong, spaceman 817, but in this context, coopersitas answer solves my problem.

Comment: No worries - glad you were able to get the fix you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just wrap your portrait images into another container?

Something like

```
.imageBox {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you have your responsive CSS set correctly, this should scale correctly with your design - just change the width to however wide you want the image.

Comment: Here is a quick example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SA8Uh/

I used responsive code from http://cssgrid.net/.

Comment: Yes, this is a right answer and it works, but this would require to add the special class to each portrait image so it can be inconvenient sometimes. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need extra markup. Setting the image to max-width, instead of with will ensure the image is nor artificially enlarged.